# native SQL query to laravel eloquent query

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I actually have two questions about this code.

```
$cash_advance = DB::select('
        SELECT p1.*, p3.fname, p3.mname, p3.lname 
        FROM cash_advance p1
        INNER JOIN(
            SELECT MAX(created_at) maxdate, customer_id
            FROM cash_advance
            GROUP BY customer_id
        ) p2
        ON p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id
        AND p1.created_at = p2.maxdate
        LEFT JOIN customer as p3 ON p1.customer_id = p3.id
        ORDER BY p1.created_at desc
```

1st is, is there any possible security flaws when using this kind of query instead of the standard eloquent query?

2nd is, how can I convert this? This is a sample code that I've been trying to do.

```
$cash_advance = DB::select('p1.*', 'p3.fname', 'p3.mname', 'p3.lname')
        ->from('cash_advance as p1')
        ->join('cash_advance as p2', function($join){
            $join->select(DB::raw('max(created_at) as maxdate'), 'customer_id')
                ->on('p2.customer_id', '=', 'p1.customer_id')
                ->on('p2.maxdate', '=', 'p1.created_at')
                ->groupBy('p2.customer_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('customer as p3', 'p1.customer_id', '=', 'p3.id')
        ->orderBy('p1.created_at', 'desc');
return \DataTables::of($cash_advance)
    ->addColumn('action', function($cash_advance){
        return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info view_cash_advance" id="'.$cash_advance->customer_id.'"><i class="material-icons" style="width: 25px;">visibility</i></button>';//info/visibility
    })
    ->make(true);
```

but datatable keeps on saying http://datatables.net/tn/7

ajax code

```
var cash_advancetable = $('#cash_advancetable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            ],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('refresh_cashadvance') }}",
            columns: [
                {render: function(data, type, full, meta){
                    return full.fname +" "+full.mname+" "+full.lname;
                }},
                {data: 'amount', name: 'amount'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                {data: 'balance', name: 'balance'},
                {data: "action", orderable:false,searchable:false}
            ]
        });
```

the first code works and I actually got the idea from another question here in stackoverflow however it was used on a native php instead of larvel so I wanted to convert it into eloquent so that it is more clean and laravel like.

Comment: Can you please use the same aliases in both queries?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir  updated my question.

Comment: it seems that my question should be for query builder and not eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't add *any* raw user input to the SQL (without using bindings), this kind of query isn't less secure.

Use this query:

```php
$join = DB::table('cash_advance')
    ->select(DB::raw('max(created_at) as maxdate'), 'customer_id')
    ->groupBy('customer_id');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') as p2';
$cash_advance = DB::table('cash_advance as p1')
    ->select('p1.*', 'p3.fname', 'p3.mname', 'p3.lname')
    ->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join){
        $join->on('p2.customer_id', '=', 'p1.customer_id')
            ->on('p2.maxdate', '=', 'p1.created_at');
    })
    ->leftJoin('customer as p3', 'p1.customer_id', '=', 'p3.id')
    ->orderBy('p1.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: The second code part replaces `->join('cash_advance as p2', function($join){...})` in your query.

Comment: and where do I insert the 1st part?

Comment: Before `$cash_advance = `.

Comment: I still have the same http://datatables.net/tn/7 error just to be clear, I'm going to include  in my question the ajax code.

Comment: You have to execute the query: `->orderBy('p1.created_at', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: I'm sorry that this may have caused some confusion but now I'm going to post the whole query including the part for the datatable. I used the get() as well but it didn't work though.

Comment: I added the whole query to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! but I hope you could explain a bit further. I actually used your past code except that I was still using select and from, in your code, you used table and select, is from not working anymore? also why does it work even without the get()?

Comment: I missed that problem at first. `DB::select($sql)` executes raw SQL (like your original query). `DB::table($table)` starts a query builder, it's equivalent to `DB::query()->from($table)`.

Comment: I actually use DB::table in most of my queries but I got so desperate in this one that I tried using DB::select() trying to imitate a raw query. my reputation is still 1 but you've got an up vote from me(not shown in public). Thank you very much!